# Freetype font initialisation error

Tags: c++, freetype, freetype2

In my font initialisation method I call FT_New_Face but no input will work for the file path parameter. I have tried passing a string with .c_str(), char array, char pointer and direct quotation input all with the same read error. Does anyone have an idea what could be causing it?

**Error:**

```
+ stream    msvcr110d.dll!0x0ff8d534 {_ptr=0xccccc35d <Error reading characters of string.> _cnt=-858993460 _base=...}  _iobuf *
```

**Code:**

```
bool FreeTypeFont::LoadFont(string filePath, int size)
{

FT_Library ft;

if(FT_Init_FreeType(&ft)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Could not init freetype library\n");
  return false;
}

//old code to try different combinations
//char temp[9];
//strcpy(temp, filePath.c_str());

FT_Face face;

if(FT_New_Face(ft, filePath.c_str(), 0, &face)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Could not open font\n");
  return false;
}
```

Comment: are you using forward or backward slashes? Do you double escape them if backward on Windows?

Comment: Backwards and yes I'm using doubles e.g. "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\comic.ttf"

Comment: You might try copying the ttf file to the local directory where the executable is to rule out any weird permissions issues, although I load fonts from the fonts directory all the time with no trouble.  You might consider using [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `FFOLDERID_Fonts` to get the directory though in case it is in a non-standard place.